RPC dependency - how do I configure it properly with CMake?
Suppose I want to build the following C program using CMake:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rpc/rpc.h>

int main()
{
        printf("Hello world\n");
        struct sockaddr_in my_address;
        get_myaddress(&my_address);
        return 0;
}

So, this program uses the RPC (remote procedure calls, RFC 1050) facilities, available on many/most modern Unix systems. The thing is, there's apparently more than one implementation of these (tirpc, ntirpc and maybe others). On the particular machine I'm working on right now (SLES 15 SP4) need to link this with -ltirpc; but that's not the case everywhere.
I am trying to figure out what to have my program depend on, as a CMake target, to ensure the linking works. This:
find_package(rpc REQUIRED)

doesn't work. There's no Findrpc module in CMake's default collection of modules.
find_package(tirpc REQUIRED)

also doesn't work, plus it's probably not the "right thing" to do.
I've seen one of the RPC implementations offer a find module, here - but I would assume that would be specific to that implementation. Or would it?
So - please help me configure this dependency the "right way".
